# Set all cookies to session cookies using web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, session-cookies

Requirements dictate that all of the cookies my application uses must expire with the users session. Is there a way to force this on every cookie using an element in my web.config?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie to expire at the end of the browser session by setting the HttpCookie.Expires property to DateTime.MinDate, or not setting the property at all.

```
HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
```

If you want the cookie to be for the session, set it to DateTime.MinValue. See the MSDN Documentation [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.expires%28VS.80%29.aspx)